# Setup laravel 5.4 with IIS 10

Tags: laravel, iis

I want to deploy laravel projects on our IIS 10, running on windows server 2016. What is the easiest and still secure way to do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is how I did it; I'm not sure it is the right way.

- Install URL Rewrite module (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)
- Put repo in some folder E:/sites/helloworld
- In IIS add a virtual directory called "helloworld" pointing to E:/sites/helloworld/public
- Make sure folders bootstrap/cache and storage is open for writing.
- Dont forget to make env file.
- In your web.php route file put:

  ```
  Route::get('/', function () {
      return view('welcome');
  });

  Route::get('/also', function () {
      return view('welcome');
  });
  ```

Add the file web.config in public dir and paste the rules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You should now be able to access both URLs meaning laravel routing works as intended. If you try another non-existent route you will get a laravel exception.