# Laravel 6.0 IIS add virtual directory HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: laravel, iis, virtual-directory

I use IIS in windows 10 host run Laravel project and on the home page it working but I click login or register it not working?

This is my setup (add virtual directory)
[image]

If localhost/tms It working 
but localhost/tms/login HTTP error 404

Comment: Thanks for contributing an answer This my answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464268/8556614](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464268/8556614)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for contributing an answer This my answer

Add the file web.config in public dir and paste th rules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Credit by
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464268/8556614